# Download Youtube audio from mp4 python

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube, python-module, jdownloader

Hello I am trying to make Python module to download YouTube videos and I am successful in getting the mp4 url of a YouTube video...
But I want to know is there any possibility to download a **mp3** file.
My idea is to change the extension of mp4 file to mp3.. But the problem is the file size...
Is there any way to download mp3 file???
Below is the dictionary that got from youtube using get_video_info..

```
{'expiresInSeconds': '21540', 'formats': [{'itag': 18, 'url': 'https://r5---sn-gwpa-pmhe.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1587474667&ei=i5yeXoa_N4TCvATE6LD4CQ&ip=2409%3A4072%3A6e19%3Ae194%3A41ab%3A1e2%3A94c9%3Ad075&id=o-AHsEKKTLH2fGqqsaBpBrpoHHJWZzx4iLyhLX-fFmRNrw&itag=18&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=TD&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-gwpa-pmhe%2Csn-h5576nee&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=4&pl=37&initcwndbps=322500&vprv=1&mime=video%2Fmp4&gir=yes&clen=439440&ratebypass=yes&dur=10.077&lmt=1432094039538727&mt=1587452973&fvip=5&fexp=23882513&c=WEB&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cvprv%2Cmime%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cratebypass%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=AJpPlLswRQIgEShHK204fUlBpaP7eqkIRO1mM71dIkrIaSYKyPQFyt8CIQCfxLAXel16l_Ij3NMF2URODeJJHqeta1GyA2_HIfByGQ%3D%3D&lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=ALrAebAwRAIgH5tO10p-_piPXwIkN6u6gKURG-HlKF258gPwwjMlbp0CIEKPN46Kkv-hq4S1S4cS9LwPyrMf0KkNq8FgIvYXJXmV', 'mimeType': 'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42001E, mp4a.40.2"', 'bitrate': 351552, 'width': 320, 'height': 176, 'lastModified': '1432094039538727', 'contentLength': '439440', 'quality': 'tiny', 'qualityLabel': '144p', 'projectionType': 'RECTANGULAR', 'averageBitrate': 348865, 'audioQuality': 'AUDIO_QUALITY_LOW', 'approxDurationMs': '10077', 'audioSampleRate': '44100', 'audioChannels': 2}], 'adaptiveFormats': [{'itag': 133, 'url': 'https://r5---sn-gwpa-pmhe.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1587474667&ei=i5yeXoa_N4TCvATE6LD4CQ&ip=2409%3A4072%3A6e19%3Ae194%3A41ab%3A1e2%3A94c9%3Ad075&id=o-AHsEKKTLH2fGqqsaBpBrpoHHJWZzx4iLyhLX-fFmRNrw&itag=133&aitags=133%2C160%2C242%2C278&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=TD&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-gwpa-pmhe%2Csn-h5576nee&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=4&pl=37&initcwndbps=322500&vprv=1&mime=video%2Fmp4&gir=yes&clen=304903&dur=10.000&lmt=1432094042313275&mt=1587452973&fvip=5&keepalive=yes&fexp=23882513&c=WEB&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Caitags%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cvprv%2Cmime%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=AJpPlLswRgIhAKzyT9aoONFF0pnNLjXMcW23MGw6Ar-QVtcGb0UH3itBAiEAzOCfYPKiVXqopaLUPtQvNg4anHSmagH0QyfzfIzVre4%3D&lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=ALrAebAwRAIgH5tO10p-_piPXwIkN6u6gKURG-HlKF258gPwwjMlbp0CIEKPN46Kkv-hq4S1S4cS9LwPyrMf0KkNq8FgIvYXJXmV', 'mimeType': 'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.4d400d"', 'bitrate': 244295, 'width': 320, 'height': 176, 'initRange': {'start': '0', 'end': '673'}, 'indexRange': {'start': '674', 'end': '729'}, 'lastModified': '1432094042313275', 'contentLength': '304903', 'quality': 'tiny', 'fps': 25, 'qualityLabel': '144p', 'projectionType': 'RECTANGULAR', 'averageBitrate': 243922, 'approxDurationMs': '10000'}, {'itag': 242, 'url': 'https://r5---sn-gwpa-pmhe.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1587474667&ei=i5yeXoa_N4TCvATE6LD4CQ&ip=2409%3A4072%3A6e19%3Ae194%3A41ab%3A1e2%3A94c9%3Ad075&id=o-AHsEKKTLH2fGqqsaBpBrpoHHJWZzx4iLyhLX-fFmRNrw&itag=242&aitags=133%2C160%2C242%2C278&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=TD&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-gwpa-pmhe%2Csn-h5576nee&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=4&pl=37&initcwndbps=322500&vprv=1&mime=video%2Fwebm&gir=yes&clen=107173&dur=10.000&lmt=1542979534576473&mt=1587452973&fvip=5&keepalive=yes&fexp=23882513&c=WEB&txp=5432432&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Caitags%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cvprv%2Cmime%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=AJpPlLswRQIhAPTj5s9RoMfgKN9BNVenWXVUukm1O8qT0DIobNRJwLYYAiBkGfGyUEmFeq8Yn35xB_dtWhS82p2MLmEiK-hc0AGB3A%3D%3D&lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=ALrAebAwRAIgH5tO10p-_piPXwIkN6u6gKURG-HlKF258gPwwjMlbp0CIEKPN46Kkv-hq4S1S4cS9LwPyrMf0KkNq8FgIvYXJXmV', 'mimeType': 'video/webm; codecs="vp9"', 'bitrate': 116835, 'width': 320, 'height': 176, 'initRange': {'start': '0', 'end': '217'}, 'indexRange': {'start': '218', 'end': '251'}, 'lastModified': '1542979534576473', 'contentLength': '107173', 'quality': 'tiny', 'fps': 25, 'qualityLabel': '144p', 'projectionType': 'RECTANGULAR', 'averageBitrate': 85738, 'colorInfo': {'transferCharacteristics': 'COLOR_TRANSFER_CHARACTERISTICS_BT709'}, 'approxDurationMs': '10000'}, {'itag': 160, 'url': 'https://r5---sn-gwpa-pmhe.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1587474667&ei=i5yeXoa_N4TCvATE6LD4CQ&ip=2409%3A4072%3A6e19%3Ae194%3A41ab%3A1e2%3A94c9%3Ad075&id=o-AHsEKKTLH2fGqqsaBpBrpoHHJWZzx4iLyhLX-fFmRNrw&itag=160&aitags=133%2C160%2C242%2C278&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=TD&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-gwpa-pmhe%2Csn-h5576nee&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=4&pl=37&initcwndbps=322500&vprv=1&mime=video%2Fmp4&gir=yes&clen=136657&dur=10.000&lmt=1432094064128819&mt=1587452973&fvip=5&keepalive=yes&fexp=23882513&c=WEB&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Caitags%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cvprv%2Cmime%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=AJpPlLswRQIgerSRvw6r4UgQ6BkPVjdbdisFJmeDgudcA9YpR9ph6-MCIQDgJAawfdx9i7cQbMCQc_YfomInnYll5WCK6Z84LRJvqg%3D%3D&lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=ALrAebAwRAIgH5tO10p-_piPXwIkN6u6gKURG-HlKF258gPwwjMlbp0CIEKPN46Kkv-hq4S1S4cS9LwPyrMf0KkNq8FgIvYXJXmV', 'mimeType': 'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.4d400c"', 'bitrate': 109912, 'width': 256, 'height': 140, 'initRange': {'start': '0', 'end': '673'}, 'indexRange': {'start': '674', 'end': '729'}, 'lastModified': '1432094064128819', 'contentLength': '136657', 'quality': 'tiny', 'fps': 13, 'qualityLabel': '144p', 'projectionType': 'RECTANGULAR', 'averageBitrate': 109325, 'approxDurationMs': '10000'}, {'itag': 278, 'url': 'https://r5---sn-gwpa-pmhe.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1587474667&ei=i5yeXoa_N4TCvATE6LD4CQ&ip=2409%3A4072%3A6e19%3Ae194%3A41ab%3A1e2%3A94c9%3Ad075&id=o-AHsEKKTLH2fGqqsaBpBrpoHHJWZzx4iLyhLX-fFmRNrw&itag=278&aitags=133%2C160%2C242%2C278&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=TD&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-gwpa-pmhe%2Csn-h5576nee&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=4&pl=37&initcwndbps=322500&vprv=1&mime=video%2Fwebm&gir=yes&clen=104056&dur=10.000&lmt=1542979534559022&mt=1587452973&fvip=5&keepalive=yes&fexp=23882513&c=WEB&txp=5432432&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Caitags%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cvprv%2Cmime%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=AJpPlLswRQIhALPHDUmX22n1_rYuk0JFU2yVzIdMufpA3RsDApEp2WOuAiB7B29tu1lpLXNaVTBNqvhUtI1EAgPf86gyfduH9MG8zg%3D%3D&lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=ALrAebAwRAIgH5tO10p-_piPXwIkN6u6gKURG-HlKF258gPwwjMlbp0CIEKPN46Kkv-hq4S1S4cS9LwPyrMf0KkNq8FgIvYXJXmV', 'mimeType': 'video/webm; codecs="vp9"', 'bitrate': 90100, 'width': 256, 'height': 140, 'initRange': {'start': '0', 'end': '217'}, 'indexRange': {'start': '218', 'end': '250'}, 'lastModified': '1542979534559022', 'contentLength': '104056', 'quality': 'tiny', 'fps': 25, 'qualityLabel': '144p', 'projectionType': 'RECTANGULAR', 'averageBitrate': 83244, 'colorInfo': {'transferCharacteristics': 'COLOR_TRANSFER_CHARACTERISTICS_BT709'}, 'approxDurationMs': '10000'}, {'itag': 140, 'url': 'https://r5---sn-gwpa-pmhe.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1587474667&ei=i5yeXoa_N4TCvATE6LD4CQ&ip=2409%3A4072%3A6e19%3Ae194%3A41ab%3A1e2%3A94c9%3Ad075&id=o-AHsEKKTLH2fGqqsaBpBrpoHHJWZzx4iLyhLX-fFmRNrw&itag=140&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=TD&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-gwpa-pmhe%2Csn-h5576nee&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=4&pl=37&initcwndbps=322500&vprv=1&mime=audio%2Fmp4&gir=yes&clen=161045&dur=10.077&lmt=1432094017096828&mt=1587452973&fvip=5&keepalive=yes&fexp=23882513&c=WEB&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cvprv%2Cmime%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=AJpPlLswRgIhAP4lT08pxvqzqFztLd6UXCJwl0Vh-vjAe8DDYEi9Sg58AiEApdUbVEOf--i70CFPbuBxvXzXgIDZ7qfKs2a4KBbaEP4%3D&lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=ALrAebAwRAIgH5tO10p-_piPXwIkN6u6gKURG-HlKF258gPwwjMlbp0CIEKPN46Kkv-hq4S1S4cS9LwPyrMf0KkNq8FgIvYXJXmV', 'mimeType': 'audio/mp4; codecs="mp4a.40.2"', 'bitrate': 141485, 'initRange': {'start': '0', 'end': '591'}, 'indexRange': {'start': '592', 'end': '647'}, 'lastModified': '1432094017096828', 'contentLength': '161045', 'quality': 'tiny', 'projectionType': 'RECTANGULAR', 'averageBitrate': 127851, 'highReplication': True, 'audioQuality': 'AUDIO_QUALITY_MEDIUM', 'approxDurationMs': '10077', 'audioSampleRate': '44100', 'audioChannels': 2}, {'itag': 249, 'url': 'https://r5---sn-gwpa-pmhe.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1587474667&ei=i5yeXoa_N4TCvATE6LD4CQ&ip=2409%3A4072%3A6e19%3Ae194%3A41ab%3A1e2%3A94c9%3Ad075&id=o-AHsEKKTLH2fGqqsaBpBrpoHHJWZzx4iLyhLX-fFmRNrw&itag=249&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=TD&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-gwpa-pmhe%2Csn-h5576nee&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=4&pl=37&initcwndbps=322500&vprv=1&mime=audio%2Fwebm&gir=yes&clen=62739&dur=10.021&lmt=1507124139667636&mt=1587452973&fvip=5&keepalive=yes&fexp=23882513&c=WEB&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cvprv%2Cmime%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=AJpPlLswRgIhAIotf6uYwcAJvV-Y194Ea8YdF1AUIJbLG5l5K3b8lYn1AiEA-GJgzgZQCu-JHMIlfINnbaMqy7U-5x7PPs7ecgHXOKM%3D&lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=ALrAebAwRAIgH5tO10p-_piPXwIkN6u6gKURG-HlKF258gPwwjMlbp0CIEKPN46Kkv-hq4S1S4cS9LwPyrMf0KkNq8FgIvYXJXmV', 'mimeType': 'audio/webm; codecs="opus"', 'bitrate': 140800, 'initRange': {'start': '0', 'end': '271'}, 'indexRange': {'start': '272', 'end': '305'}, 'lastModified': '1507124139667636', 'contentLength': '62739', 'quality': 'tiny', 'projectionType': 'RECTANGULAR', 'averageBitrate': 50086, 'audioQuality': 'AUDIO_QUALITY_LOW', 'approxDurationMs': '10021', 'audioSampleRate': '48000', 'audioChannels': 2}, {'itag': 250, 'url': 'https://r5---sn-gwpa-pmhe.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1587474667&ei=i5yeXoa_N4TCvATE6LD4CQ&ip=2409%3A4072%3A6e19%3Ae194%3A41ab%3A1e2%3A94c9%3Ad075&id=o-AHsEKKTLH2fGqqsaBpBrpoHHJWZzx4iLyhLX-fFmRNrw&itag=250&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=TD&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-gwpa-pmhe%2Csn-h5576nee&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=4&pl=37&initcwndbps=322500&vprv=1&mime=audio%2Fwebm&gir=yes&clen=82251&dur=10.021&lmt=1507124141718293&mt=1587452973&fvip=5&keepalive=yes&fexp=23882513&c=WEB&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cvprv%2Cmime%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=AJpPlLswRAIgWEZFenhwHcQQOQDb8DPWu-63up30KplyPiTYk7BqaS8CIHO9bfE-StZLT61JFZ587sgcuiHcJnZKbheJYkq9Vh4A&lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=ALrAebAwRAIgH5tO10p-_piPXwIkN6u6gKURG-HlKF258gPwwjMlbp0CIEKPN46Kkv-hq4S1S4cS9LwPyrMf0KkNq8FgIvYXJXmV', 'mimeType': 'audio/webm; codecs="opus"', 'bitrate': 183200, 'initRange': {'start': '0', 'end': '271'}, 'indexRange': {'start': '272', 'end': '306'}, 'lastModified': '1507124141718293', 'contentLength': '82251', 'quality': 'tiny', 'projectionType': 'RECTANGULAR', 'averageBitrate': 65662, 'audioQuality': 'AUDIO_QUALITY_LOW', 'approxDurationMs': '10021', 'audioSampleRate': '48000', 'audioChannels': 2}, {'itag': 251, 'url': 'https://r5---sn-gwpa-pmhe.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1587474667&ei=i5yeXoa_N4TCvATE6LD4CQ&ip=2409%3A4072%3A6e19%3Ae194%3A41ab%3A1e2%3A94c9%3Ad075&id=o-AHsEKKTLH2fGqqsaBpBrpoHHJWZzx4iLyhLX-fFmRNrw&itag=251&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=TD&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-gwpa-pmhe%2Csn-h5576nee&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=4&pl=37&initcwndbps=322500&vprv=1&mime=audio%2Fwebm&gir=yes&clen=162405&dur=10.021&lmt=1507124140437976&mt=1587452973&fvip=5&keepalive=yes&fexp=23882513&c=WEB&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cvprv%2Cmime%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=AJpPlLswRQIhAP3fuZmHtMK-lzdU7Ln6YkE6zVlj6__Qgxm9QBfRI1N1AiBqJ5VhZauf7lOTB6lsP3IX4o2oMbW-x9MmVc1gMNKmpg%3D%3D&lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=ALrAebAwRAIgH5tO10p-_piPXwIkN6u6gKURG-HlKF258gPwwjMlbp0CIEKPN46Kkv-hq4S1S4cS9LwPyrMf0KkNq8FgIvYXJXmV', 'mimeType': 'audio/webm; codecs="opus"', 'bitrate': 370400, 'initRange': {'start': '0', 'end': '271'}, 'indexRange': {'start': '272', 'end': '306'}, 'lastModified': '1507124140437976', 'contentLength': '162405', 'quality': 'tiny', 'projectionType': 'RECTANGULAR', 'averageBitrate': 129651, 'audioQuality': 'AUDIO_QUALITY_MEDIUM', 'approxDurationMs': '10021', 'audioSampleRate': '48000', 'audioChannels': 2}]}{'expiresInSeconds': '21540', 'formats': [{'itag': 18, 'url': 'https://r5---sn-gwpa-pmhe.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1587474667&ei=i5yeXoa_N4TCvATE6LD4CQ&ip=2409%3A4072%3A6e19%3Ae194%3A41ab%3A1e2%3A94c9%3Ad075&id=o-AHsEKKTLH2fGqqsaBpBrpoHHJWZzx4iLyhLX-fFmRNrw&itag=18&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=TD&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-gwpa-pmhe%2Csn-h5576nee&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=4&pl=37&initcwndbps=322500&vprv=1&mime=video%2Fmp4&gir=yes&clen=439440&ratebypass=yes&dur=10.077&lmt=1432094039538727&mt=1587452973&fvip=5&fexp=23882513&c=WEB&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cvprv%2Cmime%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cratebypass%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=AJpPlLswRQIgEShHK204fUlBpaP7eqkIRO1mM71dIkrIaSYKyPQFyt8CIQCfxLAXel16l_Ij3NMF2URODeJJHqeta1GyA2_HIfByGQ%3D%3D&lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=ALrAebAwRAIgH5tO10p-_piPXwIkN6u6gKURG-HlKF258gPwwjMlbp0CIEKPN46Kkv-hq4S1S4cS9LwPyrMf0KkNq8FgIvYXJXmV', 'mimeType': 'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42001E, mp4a.40.2"', 'bitrate': 351552, 'width': 320, 'height': 176, 'lastModified': '1432094039538727', 'contentLength': '439440', 'quality': 'tiny', 'qualityLabel': '144p', 'projectionType': 'RECTANGULAR', 'averageBitrate': 348865, 'audioQuality': 'AUDIO_QUALITY_LOW', 'approxDurationMs': '10077', 'audioSampleRate': '44100', 'audioChannels': 2}], 'adaptiveFormats': [{'itag': 133, 'url': 'https://r5---sn-gwpa-pmhe.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1587474667&ei=i5yeXoa_N4TCvATE6LD4CQ&ip=2409%3A4072%3A6e19%3Ae194%3A41ab%3A1e2%3A94c9%3Ad075&id=o-AHsEKKTLH2fGqqsaBpBrpoHHJWZzx4iLyhLX-fFmRNrw&itag=133&aitags=133%2C160%2C242%2C278&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=TD&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-gwpa-pmhe%2Csn-h5576nee&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=4&pl=37&initcwndbps=322500&vprv=1&mime=video%2Fmp4&gir=yes&clen=304903&dur=10.000&lmt=1432094042313275&mt=1587452973&fvip=5&keepalive=yes&fexp=23882513&c=WEB&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Caitags%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cvprv%2Cmime%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=AJpPlLswRgIhAKzyT9aoONFF0pnNLjXMcW23MGw6Ar-QVtcGb0UH3itBAiEAzOCfYPKiVXqopaLUPtQvNg4anHSmagH0QyfzfIzVre4%3D&lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=ALrAebAwRAIgH5tO10p-_piPXwIkN6u6gKURG-HlKF258gPwwjMlbp0CIEKPN46Kkv-hq4S1S4cS9LwPyrMf0KkNq8FgIvYXJXmV', 'mimeType': 'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.4d400d"', 'bitrate': 244295, 'width': 320, 'height': 176, 'initRange': {'start': '0', 'end': '673'}, 'indexRange': {'start': '674', 'end': '729'}, 'lastModified': '1432094042313275', 'contentLength': '304903', 'quality': 'tiny', 'fps': 25, 'qualityLabel': '144p', 'projectionType': 'RECTANGULAR', 'averageBitrate': 243922, 'approxDurationMs': '10000'}, {'itag': 242, 'url': 'https://r5---sn-gwpa-pmhe.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1587474667&ei=i5yeXoa_N4TCvATE6LD4CQ&ip=2409%3A4072%3A6e19%3Ae194%3A41ab%3A1e2%3A94c9%3Ad075&id=o-AHsEKKTLH2fGqqsaBpBrpoHHJWZzx4iLyhLX-fFmRNrw&itag=242&aitags=133%2C160%2C242%2C278&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=TD&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-gwpa-pmhe%2Csn-h5576nee&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=4&pl=37&initcwndbps=322500&vprv=1&mime=video%2Fwebm&gir=yes&clen=107173&dur=10.000&lmt=1542979534576473&mt=1587452973&fvip=5&keepalive=yes&fexp=23882513&c=WEB&txp=5432432&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Caitags%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cvprv%2Cmime%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=AJpPlLswRQIhAPTj5s9RoMfgKN9BNVenWXVUukm1O8qT0DIobNRJwLYYAiBkGfGyUEmFeq8Yn35xB_dtWhS82p2MLmEiK-hc0AGB3A%3D%3D&lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=ALrAebAwRAIgH5tO10p-_piPXwIkN6u6gKURG-HlKF258gPwwjMlbp0CIEKPN46Kkv-hq4S1S4cS9LwPyrMf0KkNq8FgIvYXJXmV', 'mimeType': 'video/webm; codecs="vp9"', 'bitrate': 116835, 'width': 320, 'height': 176, 'initRange': {'start': '0', 'end': '217'}, 'indexRange': {'start': '218', 'end': '251'}, 'lastModified': '1542979534576473', 'contentLength': '107173', 'quality': 'tiny', 'fps': 25, 'qualityLabel': '144p', 'projectionType': 'RECTANGULAR', 'averageBitrate': 85738, 'colorInfo': {'transferCharacteristics': 'COLOR_TRANSFER_CHARACTERISTICS_BT709'}, 'approxDurationMs': '10000'}, {'itag': 160, 'url': 'https://r5---sn-gwpa-pmhe.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1587474667&ei=i5yeXoa_N4TCvATE6LD4CQ&ip=2409%3A4072%3A6e19%3Ae194%3A41ab%3A1e2%3A94c9%3Ad075&id=o-AHsEKKTLH2fGqqsaBpBrpoHHJWZzx4iLyhLX-fFmRNrw&itag=160&aitags=133%2C160%2C242%2C278&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=TD&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-gwpa-pmhe%2Csn-h5576nee&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=4&pl=37&initcwndbps=322500&vprv=1&mime=video%2Fmp4&gir=yes&clen=136657&dur=10.000&lmt=1432094064128819&mt=1587452973&fvip=5&keepalive=yes&fexp=23882513&c=WEB&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Caitags%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cvprv%2Cmime%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=AJpPlLswRQIgerSRvw6r4UgQ6BkPVjdbdisFJmeDgudcA9YpR9ph6-MCIQDgJAawfdx9i7cQbMCQc_YfomInnYll5WCK6Z84LRJvqg%3D%3D&lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=ALrAebAwRAIgH5tO10p-_piPXwIkN6u6gKURG-HlKF258gPwwjMlbp0CIEKPN46Kkv-hq4S1S4cS9LwPyrMf0KkNq8FgIvYXJXmV', 'mimeType': 'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.4d400c"', 'bitrate': 109912, 'width': 256, 'height': 140, 'initRange': {'start': '0', 'end': '673'}, 'indexRange': {'start': '674', 'end': '729'}, 'lastModified': '1432094064128819', 'contentLength': '136657', 'quality': 'tiny', 'fps': 13, 'qualityLabel': '144p', 'projectionType': 'RECTANGULAR', 'averageBitrate': 109325, 'approxDurationMs': '10000'}, {'itag': 278, 'url': 'https://r5---sn-gwpa-pmhe.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1587474667&ei=i5yeXoa_N4TCvATE6LD4CQ&ip=2409%3A4072%3A6e19%3Ae194%3A41ab%3A1e2%3A94c9%3Ad075&id=o-AHsEKKTLH2fGqqsaBpBrpoHHJWZzx4iLyhLX-fFmRNrw&itag=278&aitags=133%2C160%2C242%2C278&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=TD&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-gwpa-pmhe%2Csn-h5576nee&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=4&pl=37&initcwndbps=322500&vprv=1&mime=video%2Fwebm&gir=yes&clen=104056&dur=10.000&lmt=1542979534559022&mt=1587452973&fvip=5&keepalive=yes&fexp=23882513&c=WEB&txp=5432432&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Caitags%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cvprv%2Cmime%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=AJpPlLswRQIhALPHDUmX22n1_rYuk0JFU2yVzIdMufpA3RsDApEp2WOuAiB7B29tu1lpLXNaVTBNqvhUtI1EAgPf86gyfduH9MG8zg%3D%3D&lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=ALrAebAwRAIgH5tO10p-_piPXwIkN6u6gKURG-HlKF258gPwwjMlbp0CIEKPN46Kkv-hq4S1S4cS9LwPyrMf0KkNq8FgIvYXJXmV', 'mimeType': 'video/webm; codecs="vp9"', 'bitrate': 90100, 'width': 256, 'height': 140, 'initRange': {'start': '0', 'end': '217'}, 'indexRange': {'start': '218', 'end': '250'}, 'lastModified': '1542979534559022', 'contentLength': '104056', 'quality': 'tiny', 'fps': 25, 'qualityLabel': '144p', 'projectionType': 'RECTANGULAR', 'averageBitrate': 83244, 'colorInfo': {'transferCharacteristics': 'COLOR_TRANSFER_CHARACTERISTICS_BT709'}, 'approxDurationMs': '10000'}, {'itag': 140, 'url': 'https://r5---sn-gwpa-pmhe.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1587474667&ei=i5yeXoa_N4TCvATE6LD4CQ&ip=2409%3A4072%3A6e19%3Ae194%3A41ab%3A1e2%3A94c9%3Ad075&id=o-AHsEKKTLH2fGqqsaBpBrpoHHJWZzx4iLyhLX-fFmRNrw&itag=140&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=TD&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-gwpa-pmhe%2Csn-h5576nee&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=4&pl=37&initcwndbps=322500&vprv=1&mime=audio%2Fmp4&gir=yes&clen=161045&dur=10.077&lmt=1432094017096828&mt=1587452973&fvip=5&keepalive=yes&fexp=23882513&c=WEB&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cvprv%2Cmime%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=AJpPlLswRgIhAP4lT08pxvqzqFztLd6UXCJwl0Vh-vjAe8DDYEi9Sg58AiEApdUbVEOf--i70CFPbuBxvXzXgIDZ7qfKs2a4KBbaEP4%3D&lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=ALrAebAwRAIgH5tO10p-_piPXwIkN6u6gKURG-HlKF258gPwwjMlbp0CIEKPN46Kkv-hq4S1S4cS9LwPyrMf0KkNq8FgIvYXJXmV', 'mimeType': 'audio/mp4; codecs="mp4a.40.2"', 'bitrate': 141485, 'initRange': {'start': '0', 'end': '591'}, 'indexRange': {'start': '592', 'end': '647'}, 'lastModified': '1432094017096828', 'contentLength': '161045', 'quality': 'tiny', 'projectionType': 'RECTANGULAR', 'averageBitrate': 127851, 'highReplication': True, 'audioQuality': 'AUDIO_QUALITY_MEDIUM', 'approxDurationMs': '10077', 'audioSampleRate': '44100', 'audioChannels': 2}, {'itag': 249, 'url': 'https://r5---sn-gwpa-pmhe.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1587474667&ei=i5yeXoa_N4TCvATE6LD4CQ&ip=2409%3A4072%3A6e19%3Ae194%3A41ab%3A1e2%3A94c9%3Ad075&id=o-AHsEKKTLH2fGqqsaBpBrpoHHJWZzx4iLyhLX-fFmRNrw&itag=249&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=TD&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-gwpa-pmhe%2Csn-h5576nee&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=4&pl=37&initcwndbps=322500&vprv=1&mime=audio%2Fwebm&gir=yes&clen=62739&dur=10.021&lmt=1507124139667636&mt=1587452973&fvip=5&keepalive=yes&fexp=23882513&c=WEB&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cvprv%2Cmime%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=AJpPlLswRgIhAIotf6uYwcAJvV-Y194Ea8YdF1AUIJbLG5l5K3b8lYn1AiEA-GJgzgZQCu-JHMIlfINnbaMqy7U-5x7PPs7ecgHXOKM%3D&lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=ALrAebAwRAIgH5tO10p-_piPXwIkN6u6gKURG-HlKF258gPwwjMlbp0CIEKPN46Kkv-hq4S1S4cS9LwPyrMf0KkNq8FgIvYXJXmV', 'mimeType': 'audio/webm; codecs="opus"', 'bitrate': 140800, 'initRange': {'start': '0', 'end': '271'}, 'indexRange': {'start': '272', 'end': '305'}, 'lastModified': '1507124139667636', 'contentLength': '62739', 'quality': 'tiny', 'projectionType': 'RECTANGULAR', 'averageBitrate': 50086, 'audioQuality': 'AUDIO_QUALITY_LOW', 'approxDurationMs': '10021', 'audioSampleRate': '48000', 'audioChannels': 2}, {'itag': 250, 'url': 'https://r5---sn-gwpa-pmhe.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1587474667&ei=i5yeXoa_N4TCvATE6LD4CQ&ip=2409%3A4072%3A6e19%3Ae194%3A41ab%3A1e2%3A94c9%3Ad075&id=o-AHsEKKTLH2fGqqsaBpBrpoHHJWZzx4iLyhLX-fFmRNrw&itag=250&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=TD&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-gwpa-pmhe%2Csn-h5576nee&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=4&pl=37&initcwndbps=322500&vprv=1&mime=audio%2Fwebm&gir=yes&clen=82251&dur=10.021&lmt=1507124141718293&mt=1587452973&fvip=5&keepalive=yes&fexp=23882513&c=WEB&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cvprv%2Cmime%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=AJpPlLswRAIgWEZFenhwHcQQOQDb8DPWu-63up30KplyPiTYk7BqaS8CIHO9bfE-StZLT61JFZ587sgcuiHcJnZKbheJYkq9Vh4A&lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=ALrAebAwRAIgH5tO10p-_piPXwIkN6u6gKURG-HlKF258gPwwjMlbp0CIEKPN46Kkv-hq4S1S4cS9LwPyrMf0KkNq8FgIvYXJXmV', 'mimeType': 'audio/webm; codecs="opus"', 'bitrate': 183200, 'initRange': {'start': '0', 'end': '271'}, 'indexRange': {'start': '272', 'end': '306'}, 'lastModified': '1507124141718293', 'contentLength': '82251', 'quality': 'tiny', 'projectionType': 'RECTANGULAR', 'averageBitrate': 65662, 'audioQuality': 'AUDIO_QUALITY_LOW', 'approxDurationMs': '10021', 'audioSampleRate': '48000', 'audioChannels': 2}, {'itag': 251, 'url': 'https://r5---sn-gwpa-pmhe.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1587474667&ei=i5yeXoa_N4TCvATE6LD4CQ&ip=2409%3A4072%3A6e19%3Ae194%3A41ab%3A1e2%3A94c9%3Ad075&id=o-AHsEKKTLH2fGqqsaBpBrpoHHJWZzx4iLyhLX-fFmRNrw&itag=251&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=TD&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-gwpa-pmhe%2Csn-h5576nee&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=4&pl=37&initcwndbps=322500&vprv=1&mime=audio%2Fwebm&gir=yes&clen=162405&dur=10.021&lmt=1507124140437976&mt=1587452973&fvip=5&keepalive=yes&fexp=23882513&c=WEB&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cvprv%2Cmime%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=AJpPlLswRQIhAP3fuZmHtMK-lzdU7Ln6YkE6zVlj6__Qgxm9QBfRI1N1AiBqJ5VhZauf7lOTB6lsP3IX4o2oMbW-x9MmVc1gMNKmpg%3D%3D&lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=ALrAebAwRAIgH5tO10p-_piPXwIkN6u6gKURG-HlKF258gPwwjMlbp0CIEKPN46Kkv-hq4S1S4cS9LwPyrMf0KkNq8FgIvYXJXmV', 'mimeType': 'audio/webm; codecs="opus"', 'bitrate': 370400, 'initRange': {'start': '0', 'end': '271'}, 'indexRange': {'start': '272', 'end': '306'}, 'lastModified': '1507124140437976', 'contentLength': '162405', 'quality': 'tiny', 'projectionType': 'RECTANGULAR', 'averageBitrate': 129651, 'audioQuality': 'AUDIO_QUALITY_MEDIUM', 'approxDurationMs': '10021', 'audioSampleRate': '48000', 'audioChannels': 2}]}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26548884/is-there-a-youtube-api-that-gives-only-audio this answer says, that the Youtube API doesn't provide an "audio only" download option, and they don't allow separation of content via the API. So your only choice would be to download the full video file, and then extract the audio from it.

Comment: @Teemu But does it make the process longer?? I want to know how ytmp3.cc processing video to audio.... Please tell me, if you know... Thanks again

Comment: Yes, that would most likely make the process longer as you have to download more data. There are more suggestions in that answer for alternative methods, but know that separating content during the download is strictly prohibited by YouTube's policy.

Answer (score 0):

To just add `'preferredcodec' : 'mp3'` seems a plausible solution.

Comment: asking a question in an answer is not how answers are written in stackoverflow, I would suggest reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @bhucho Sorry, but an answer which answer in the shape of a rhetoric question is still a non-flaggable answer. For being unclear and confusing it can only be downvoted.

Comment: ok, I will have a read through stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer!

Answer (score 0):

I made an applicaion for this , it uses yt-dlp and youtube api , this allows a user to search and download any youtube video or audio , I also added the lyricsgenius library to allow for lyrics downloads for songs
https://github.com/jacobDebrone/downloader.git